# Nginx route with single page app

Tags: nginx, centos7

I'm starting to go nuts at this. For some reason, routing wont work on my single page application. So www.example.com works, but not www.example.com/service. I read a lot of posts on how to fix it, but nothing seems to work.

This is my config file at /etc/nginx/conf.d/App.conf

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com *.example.com;
  return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name www.example.com;
  ssl_certificate /path/to/certificate/;
  ssl_certificate_key /path/to/certificate/key;

  root /var/www/App/public;
  index index.html;
  location / {
    try_files $uri /index.html;
  }
  ssl_session_timeout 5;
}
```

I have tried all kind of different "location" routes, and nothing seems to work. I do also restart the service with "sudo service nginx restart" everytime I change.
Any clues?

Comment: You haven't told us what "service" is. A subdirectory of `/var/www/App/public`? If you enter "www.example.com/service/" (with a slash), does that work?

Comment: It is a single page application. All routing should go back to the index file, and the code should render a specific code depending on the route. EDIT: To clarify if I was a bit unclear; the error 404 isn't routing back to index

Comment: Are there many other possibilitiies for the path component(s) of the URI, apart from "service"? Or just a small fixed set of possibilities?

Comment: There are 4 fixed set of possibilities.
This is my  site: https://zoomicweb.com/
as you might see, you can enter the site and see all the components/pages. but if you take the url https://zoomicweb.com/services, it doesnt work.

Comment: It might worth considering modifying your requirements. Using internal links (`href="#anchor"`) might be easier. Requesting the same resource from different locations defeats layers of caching you would otherwise get by default.

Answer (score 0):

In the comments you said there's a small fixed set of possible routes. In that case you can add a location block for each route, with an alias to the top-level, for example,

```
    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location /services {
            alias /var/www/App/public;
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
```

**Edit:** Or, if you want to serve the top-level index.html in response to any request at all,

```
    location / {
            try_files /index.html =404;
    }
```